# Add sending authorization policy to SES identity with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ses

Is there a way to add a sending authorization policy to a SES identity defined in a cloudformation template?

Defined this identity, but I can't find how I could add here the policy, which is easy to do in management console:

```
Resources:
    userEmailIdentity:
        Type: AWS::PinpointEmail::Identity
        Properties:
            Name: !Ref EmailAddress
```